# Page/Post path in Search Results

Tags: search, breadcrumb, paths

I have lots of pages with similar titles which may be confusing when users search for something. To help them tell apart the pages, I'd like to add the page/post location (path) **under each page/post title** on the Search Results page. Is it possible?

Sample SEARCH RESULTS output:

**Post Title 1**

Home -> News -> Events -> Post Title 1
[content]
[read more]

**Page Title A**

Home -> About -> Page Title A
[content]
[read more]

Comment: Yes, it's possible indeed. [A simple Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=WordPress+Breadcrumb), and I used WordPress SEO's Inner Links (breadcrumb code) - works well for me.

Comment: I know what breadcrumbs are, and that's not what I need.

Comment: O, I'm sorry! I misunderstood your question. You can follow [this code](http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-cat/adding-wordpress-breadcrumbs-without-a-plugin/), though it's also a breadcrumb code, but you can have a look at the category portion. The code shows multiple categories, if the post is assigned so. You can use them to make your self path-to-post in Search result.

Comment: Search results return both posts and pages, not just posts. Thanks for trying, but that still wouldn't work.

Comment: I don't actually know, but I think in that case, you need a conditional, like [`is_single()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) (replaced `is_post()`) and [`is_page()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution for this?

Comment: @KerynGill - no, I haven't. Found this though and will be trying out this week: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302801/wordpress-breadcrumbs-in-search-results